# PHP - Searching for a file in a directory and finding its extension

Tags: php, directory

I have a directory - `.../dir` - that contains many files - `john.txt`, `bob.txt`, `anne.pdf`, `tom.txt`, etc...

I am given a file name, and need to retreive its extension. I have high confidence that for each filename (ie `john`, `bob`, etc), there is only one file - so there shouldn't be a case when there's both `john.txt` and `john.pdf`. But let's say in case that this happens, picking only the first file is ok. Let's say PDF since it's earlier alphabetically.

I only found scandir(), but it returns the whole directory. I could search the array it retrns, but I'm hoping, maybe there's something more efficient?

Comment: Did you mean `.../dir` or `../dir` ?

Comment: Did you mean `.../dir` or `../dir` ?

Comment: Ah, well I just meant [...some path leading up to dir...]/dir. Didn't mean anything specific by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [`pathinfo()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function for getting an extension.

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

As for searching file, in particular, directory you can use a [`glob()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function

```
$file = glob("../dir/jon.*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$filename = 'ana';

$files = glob($filename . '.*');
if ($files && ($ext = pathinfo($files[0], PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) {
    echo $ext;
}
```